# ImportError while importing PySide2

Tags: python, qt, importerror, pyside2

I installed PySide2 using `pip install PySide2`

But i got this error when i tried to import it:

```
>>> import PySide2
PySide2/__init__.py: Unable to import shiboken2 from , C:\Users\ilia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\idlelib, C:\Users\ilia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python38.zip, C:\Users\ilia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\DLLs, C:\Users\ilia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib, C:\Users\ilia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38, C:\Users\ilia\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages, C:\Users\ilia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    import PySide2
  File "C:\Users\ilia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PySide2\__init__.py", line 107, in <module>
    _setupQtDirectories()
  File "C:\Users\ilia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PySide2\__init__.py", line 58, in _setupQtDirectories
    import shiboken2
  File "C:\Users\ilia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\shiboken2\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .shiboken2 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing shiboken2: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

```
OS = Windows 10
python = 3.8.0
Pyside2 = 5.15.2
shiboken2 = 5.15.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the PyPI documentation [here](https://pypi.org/project/PySide2/).
If that doesn't help try to use

```
pip show pyside2
```

Make sure it is installede in your virtual environtment if you are using that and you are using the correct version of pip(3).

[Here](https://forum.learnpyqt.com/t/unable-to-import-anything-from-pyside2/202/4) is a person that is facing a similar problem.